# Números cúbicos en C++

Tags: c++

Como puedo encontrar los números cúbicos en C++, pero solamente sumando, sin 
   usar multiplicaciones como tal, " * ". Esto debe de ir en un arreglo 
   de 15.

```
void Cubicos (){

  for (int i = 1; i <=15; i++){
      B[i] = pow(i,3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola, la verdad no entiendo bien tu pregunta. ¿Podrías explicar un poco mejor qué deseas hacer?

Comment: ¿te refieres a usar recursividad?

Comment: ¿ Que es para ti un `número cúbico` ? ¿ Que quiere decir `Esto debe ir en un arreglo de 15` ? ¿ Qué es `B[ ]` ? ¿ Como lo recibe esa función `Cubicos( )` ? Quizás deberías pasarte por [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: La función me debe generar los primeros 15 números cúbicos (8, 27, 36, 64, 125...), sin multiplicación, todo tiene que ser generado a pura suma. B[ ] es un arreglo unidimensional de 15 posiciones.

Comment: Eso que tu llamas `números cúbicos` es el conjunto de todos los `y = x^3`, donde `x` pertenece a los números enteros positivos. Además sólo deseas los primeros 15 elementos. ¿Cierto?.

Comment: Es correcto, @MauricioContreras . Así como tengo esa función `Cubicos`  me los genera, sin ningún problema, pero tengo que hacerlo con sumas nada mas.